# how to enforce same label height of shiny inputs?

Tags: r, shiny

## Problem Description

For a Shiny app I want to display multiple `selectInputs` side by side in a Row like Layout in my app. Unfortunately the select fields do not line up if there is a line break within a label which destroys the flow of the app.

## Situation

This is my example code, i modified the example in the description of `selectInput`:

```r
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  
  
  
  # demoing group support in the `choices` arg
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      mainPanel(
        flowLayout(
          selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                      list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                           `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                           `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA")),
          ),
          selectInput("stat2", "Variable description with a way longer description to enforce linebreak:",
                      list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                           `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                           `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA")),
          )),# end of inputs
        
        textOutput("result"),
        width = 12
      )),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$result <- renderText({
        paste("You chose", input$state)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

which results in:

[image: Failed formatting]

## Target

I would like to always have the input fields on the same height level, like this:

[image: wishful Layout]

`splitLayout` kind of does this, but it breaks down if the page is to narrow for the labels and adds y-scrollers which are complicating the UI, especially for bigger Labels:
[image: Splitlayout]

Unfortunately I have no experience in WebDev and therefore am a bit overwhelmed. Can someone help me out with this Problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS does the trick.

```
style = "display:flex;align-items:flex-end"
```

Does including this style in flowLayout help you with your problem?

```
if (interactive()) {
  
  
  
  # demoing group support in the `choices` arg
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      mainPanel(
        flowLayout(
          style = "display:flex;align-items:flex-end",
          selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                      list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                           `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                           `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA")),
          ),
          selectInput("stat2", "Variable description with a way longer description to enforce linebreak:",
                      list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                           `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                           `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA")),
          )),# end of inputs
        
        textOutput("result"),
        width = 12
      )),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$result <- renderText({
        paste("You chose", input$state)
      })
    }
  )
}
```